# How to do a case-sensitive match in an IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing an IF Statement and want an exact match.

```
IF ( @a_Action <> 'Power On' AND @a_Action <> 'Power Off' AND @a_Action <> 'Reset' )
BEGIN
    -- Invalid action - an IPMI command. 
    -- Set call as failed.
    SELECT @ErrorSw = 'Y'
    SELECT @ApiResultOut = 0
    SELECT @ApiResultCodeOut = 1610
    SELECT @ApiMessageOut = 'Warning - action type "' + @a_Action + '" is not a valid server (IPMI) command.'
END
```

If the @a_Action parameter is sent in as "Power on", it will pass and not error out. Only the exact match should pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a_Action VARCHAR(20)
SET @a_Action = 'Power on' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

IF (@a_Action = 'Power On' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
    PRINT 'match'
ELSE
    PRINT 'not match'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @A varchar(10) = 'Power on' 

IF @A COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT IN ( 'Power On', 'Power Off', 'Reset' ) 
BEGIN
    Print 'Invalid command'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'OK command'
END ;
```